# Can we avoid nested queries when tables are already joined in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 2 tables like this, the main Entity and one to represent the Statuses of the Entity, including the old ones.

```
> entity
id, current_status_id

> status
id, entity_id, name
```

I wrote a query like this, to return the entity items that currently have a given status

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM entity e
INNER JOIN status s ON e.current_status_id = s.id
WHERE name = $some_status
```

But let`s say I want to add a filter to this query that already has a join between Status and Entity. For example: if it had another status in the past. So *"select items with a given status that had another status in the past"*

I would add this to the end of the previous query:

```
AND e.id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM status WHERE name = $another_status)
```

I wonder if in situations like that nesting a query is necessary since this table is already joined. Is there a shortcut or a good practice for that?

Thanks

Comment: please tag only the database that you are using

Comment: ok. i added the databases that I usually work with, but it`s not a system related question

Comment: Could you please add some testing data and expected output?  It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: How do you know what status an entity had in the past, if you only store `current_status_id`? I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @HoneyBadger status has the entity id. read it again

Comment: @VictorFerreira, please add sample data like you've been asked a couple of times. You have way to much rep to leave people guessing.

Comment: @HoneyBadger this is more like a conceptual question. of course I can add data example, tough it will be very simple and almost unnecessary. the person asked that and then deleted his answer. this usually happens when people answer fast and they dont have enough time to think about the problem.

Comment: @VictorFerreira thinking about a problem is greatly ameliorated by a data sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a subquery or one more join because you try to get two independent subsets of the `status` table

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM entity e
INNER JOIN status s ON e.current_status_id = s.id
WHERE name = $some_status
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM status
        WHERE name = $another_status
        AND entity_id = e.id
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple conditions in the `ON` clause

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM entity e
INNER JOIN status s
  ON e.current_status_id = s.id
  AND s.name IN ('$some_status', '$another_status')
```

but it should be working exactly the same way as having it in the where clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM entity e, status s
WHERE e.current_status_id = s.id
AND s.name IN ('$some_status', '$another_status')
```

Comment: Just proposing a version with archaic `JOIN` syntax is distasteful.

Answer (score 0):

You could use  the same table using alias

```
SELECT e.* 
FROM entity e
INNER JOIN status s1 ON e.current_status_id = s1.id  
    and  s1.name = $some_status
INNER JOIN status s2 ON e.current_status_id = s2.id  
    and  s2.name = $another_status
```

Comment: hmm I see. in this case we are joining the table, again right? so we are creating more tuples than just joining the first time? (im not comparing with a nested query that clearly has a high cost)

Comment: in this way you have the two result set for the two query but matching value just one time for each join (and not looping for each value as for an in clause).. Normally the use of join is more performant respect  the in clause  .. obviously in presence of proper index